# update mysql datarow from php form with button

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a php form that holds a few rows of mysql data. I have a button next to each row and when i click on that I want to update the row. The issue im having below is the ID is only set as the last row. How do i get this to push the ID to the button? So basically no matter what button i press i always get the same ID which is the last one to load.

```
    if($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $row["ID"];
            $beername = $row["BeerName"];
            $beertype = $row["BeerType"];
            $beerpercent = $row["BeerPercent"];
            $beerdescription = $row["BeerDescription"];
            $nowpouring = $row["NowPouring"] =='0' ? '' : 'checked=\"checked\"';
            $glutenreduced = $row["GlutenReduced"] =='0' ? '' : 'checked=\"checked\"';
            $beertogo = $row["BeerToGo"] =='0' ? '' : 'checked=\"checked\"';

            echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
            echo "<tr><td><h6><input type=\"text\" size=\"5\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\"></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6><input type=\"text\" size=\"30\" name=\"BeerName\" value=\"$beername\"></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6><input type=\"text\" size=\"30\" name=\"BeerType\" value=\"$beertype\"></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6><textarea size=\"90\" style=\"width:250px;height:150px;\" name=\"BeerDescription\" value=\"\">$beerdescription</textarea></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6><input type=\"text\" size=\"5\" name=\"Percent\" value=\"$beerpercent\"></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"NowPouring\" value=\"true\" $nowpouring></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"GlutenReduced\" value=\"true\" $glutenreduced></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"BeerToGo\" value=\"true\" $beertogo></h6></td>";
            #echo "<td><h6> <a href=\". $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] .?id=".mysql_result($result,$j,'id')."\" onclick=\"\"></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6> <button name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"$id\">Save</button></h6></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
    }



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = $_POST['submit'];
    echo "<p style=\"color:#ffffff\">$id</p>";
    #$delet_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE NowPouring SET NowPouring = '1' WHERE ID = '4'") or die(mysql_error());

    if ($delet_query) {
        echo '<p style="color:#ffffff">Beer with id '.$id.' is updated. To refresh your page, click ' . ' <a href=' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . ' > here </a></p>';
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: I will try all these suggestions and get back to you. thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: cant edit my original code but I moved the form action into the while row, and have also tried Maximiliano Paoletti suggestion, but still getting the same id number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I see here is that the while loop your code has is generating the same name for the inputs...

All of your "`<button name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"$id\">Save</button>`" will have the same name, that's why it always has the last id as value.

Maybe you should try something such as..

```
<button name=\"$id_submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"$id\">Save</button>
```

or if you want you can store it in an array..

```
<button name=\"submit[]\" type=\"submit\" value=\"$id\">Save</button>
```

Comment: i think my issue is with this part. I still cant get it to work.

Comment: Which one are you trying to do? use the id to set the different names? or create the array for the button name.

Comment: trying to use the id to set different name. I am not sure if i need something on my form action, or on my button tag. really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've actually just tested your code.. it shows the value on each button and even though the submits all have the same name it has no problem whatsoever..

Comment: $query = " SELECT * FROM Table"
$result = $db->query($query); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = $_POST['submit'];
echo "<p>USER: $user</p>";
}

    if($result){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
            echo "<tr><td><h6><input type=\"text\" size=\"5\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\"></h6></td>";
            echo "<td><h6> <button name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"$id\">Save</button></h6></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        } }

Comment: Thats pretty much the code i used for testing. It showed the id's.. I use mysql instead of mysqli. But try to adapt it and give it a go. See if works out for you. But with the same code you have, i had no problem in echoing the correct ID for each submit

Comment: im working on it now. i will let you know. thanks again sir.

Comment: This works my friend. Thank you so much. I think i was missing the $user = $_POST['submit']; line. I will mark this as the answer as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag is placed at the wrong place.
It should be within:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $id = $row["ID"];
   //....
   //....
   echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
   echo"<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
     //....
     //....
     echo "<td><button type='submit' name='submit'>Save</button></td>";
   echo"</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
 }
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that i miss placed the form closing tag only after I posted the answer. Corrected :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this result because the 'name' of each of your inputs is the same, so essentially you have a form with a bunch of elements that have the same names. You need to add a dynamic aspect to each name.

For example, you could update your output to something like this:

```
 echo "<tr><td><h6><input type=\"text\" size=\"5\" name=\"id_$id\" value=\"$id\"></h6></td>";
```

Where each line adds the current id. Then when you retrieve the form data, you can append the submitted id to the field you want to update.

Have you considered using an AJAX approach so you can submit just the line in question and not have to reload the page and return the whole data set each time?

Comment: I am not familiar with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Make `<form>` for each submit button. Adding `<form>` in the `while()`:

```
if($result){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
    //...
    echo "</form>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Made these changes but im still getting the same id no matter what button pressed.